# Python - unorderable types: Car() > int

Tags: python

I keep getting this error:

```
in move_the_car

if self.car_fuel > x_count + y_count:

TypeError: unorderable types: Car() > int()
```

From this code:

```
if self.fuel > x_count + y_count:
```

I've heard global can resolve this, but I'm not sure how. If anyone has any other solutions or answer, I will be very grateful. Also I am a beginner in coding and python, so my code may not be written the best, but I am always looking to improve.

Entire code

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, id_, fuel, x_pos, y_pos):
        """
        @type self: Car
        @type id_: str
        @type fuel: int
        @rtype: None
        """
        self.id = id_
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos


    @property
    def id_(self):
        return self.id

    @id_.setter
    def id_(self, value):
        if value != str:
            raise ValueError()
        else:
            self.id = value

    @property
    def car_fuel(self):
        return self.fuel

    @car_fuel.setter
    def car_fuel(self, value):
         if value < 0:
             raise ValueError()
         else:
             self.fuel = value

    def move_the_car(self, id_, new_x_pos, new_y_pos):
        """
        @type self: Car
        @type id_: str
        @type new_x_pos: int
        @type new_y_pos: int

        @rtype: None
        """

        x_count = 0
        y_count = 0


        while x_count != abs(new_x_pos):
            x_count += 1

        while y_count != abs(new_y_pos):
            y_count += 1

        # if fuel level is greater than the movement counter, then return
        # the new x and y positions
        if self.fuel > x_count + y_count:
            new_fuel_level = self._fuel - (x_count + y_count)
            self._fuel = new_fuel_level
            self.x_pos = new_x_pos
            self.y_pos = new_y_pos
            new_pos = [self.x_pos, self.y_pos]
            return new_pos
        elif 0 < self.fuel < (x_count + y_count):
            new_pos = [self.x_pos, self.y_pos]
            return new_pos
        elif self.fuel <= 0:
            old_pos = [self.x_pos, self.y_pos]
            return old_pos

        else:
            return None
```

**Example:**

```
test_car = Car('car1', 10, 0, 0) #id = 'car1', fuel = 10, x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0
print(test_car) # works fine
print(test_car.car_fuel) #works fine, gives 10
print(test_car.fuel) # works fine, gives 10

print(test_car.move_the_car('car1', 2, 3))  # works fine, gives [2,3]
```

**I also call this class in another class, this may be the problem.**

```
class CarManager:

def __init__(self):
    self._cars = {}


def add_car(self, id_, fuel):
    """Add a new car to the system"""


    if id_ not in self._cars:
        self._cars[id_] = Car(id_, fuel, 0, 0)
        return self._cars[id_]
    else:
        return None

def move_car(self, id_, new_x, new_y):
    """Move the car with the given id.
    """

    if id_ not in self._cars:
        return None

    else:
        car_pos = Car(id_, self._cars[id_], new_x, new_y)
        return car_pos.move_the_car(id_, new_x, new_y)
```

**The last part may be the problem:**

```
def move_car(self, id_, new_x, new_y):
    """Move the car with the given id.
    """

    if id_ not in self._cars:
        return None

    else:
        car_pos = Car(id_, self._cars[id_], new_x, new_y)
        return car_pos.move_the_car(id_, new_x, new_y)
```

Comment: Are you meaning to write to `self.fuel` under `@id_.setter`?

Comment: Try adding some print statements to validate your assumptions ns about what is stored in your variables. Or, do you really expect to be able to compare a car to a number?

Comment: @101 that is a mistake, good catch, fixed, but still gives same error

Comment: You don't show how the `Car` instance is initialized.  Please study [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update the question.

Comment: You haven't shown enough of your code to reproduce the problem: there's a class definition but no code to use the class. Because you don't understand the problem (if you did you wouldn't be asking a question), you are not qualified to decide what code is or isn't relevant, or what code contains the error :-) So, show enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley I did test = Car('car1', 10, 0, 0), print(test), and print(test.fuel) --> it breaks on print(test.fuel) which gives error AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'fuel'

Comment: Car has no `fuel`, you make it very clear that it has a private `_fuel`, however you sometimes refer to that as `self.fuel` and sometimes as `self._fuel` which are different things

Comment: @John1024 sorry, please check now

Comment: @SteveJessop sorry, please check now

Comment: @RafaelCardoso even if i changed it to self.fuel it gives me this error

Comment: You created an object called `test_car` and then called `print test.fuel` is that correct?

Comment: Your attribute name is ```car_fuel```.  Anyway, I couldn't reproduce with ```.car_fuel > int```

Comment: @RafaelCardoso typo, should be print test_car.fuel

Comment: So whats your problem now?

Comment: @Theo (1) the error message given at the end of the updated question has nothing to do with the error message originally mentioned.  (2) the new error message is because `Car` has no attribute `fuel`.  (3) `test_car.fuel` will not work because there is no object named `test_car`.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso if self.car_fuel > x_count + y_count:   , is giving me a TypeError: unorderable types: Car() > int()

Comment: @John1024 test_car is an object, and Car has attribute car_fuel no?

Comment: It works here lol

Comment: @Theo OK.  Very good.  I see your update now.  (When I copied and pasted the code, the instance was called `test`.)

Comment: @RafaelCardoso  hmm seems like the print version of it is working

Answer (score 1):

> if self.car_fuel > x_count + y_count:
>
> TypeError: unorderable types: Car() > int()

This is telling you that at some point you've assigned a *Car* instance to `self.car_fuel` when you likely intended to assign an *int* or a *float*.

Comment: I do call it somewhere else, please check code again. I've updated of an instance where I call it in another class.